# On meta sites, the link in "Why was your post deleted? See the faq." takes to a not existing section of the FAQ

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, site-faq

On a meta site, similarly to what happens on the main site, deleted answers shows the following sentence.

> Why was your post deleted? See the [faq](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion).

The linked section doesn't exist in the meta site, and users cannot read anything about why an answer could be deleted.

[image: screenshot]

The section should be added also for the meta site, and probably adapted.